# Calculating probabilities for complex random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am having some trouble understanding/formulating how one computes probabilites given a (somehow complex) continuous random variable. For example, if I define a random variable $Z$ as: $Y=10(2+\mu+\sigma X)$ where $X$ has standard normal distribution. How would I, for example, formulate/define $P(Y>0)$ for some $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

I am thinking, since $X\sim N(0,1)$ I could use the p.d.f of the standard normal distribution to find the probabilities. But I fail to understand on how I would plugin the values into $\Phi$, for example what happens with the constant $20$? Any elaboration on this would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "complex" do you mean *complicated* or something involving $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: I mean complicated. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\sigma \gt 0$, from $Y=10(2+\mu+\sigma X)$  you could say $X = \dfrac{Y-20-10 \mu}{10\sigma}$.

So $P(Y \gt 0)$ is equivalent to $P\left(X \gt \dfrac{-2- \mu}{\sigma} \right) =  1 - \Phi\left(\dfrac{-2- \mu}{\sigma} \right)$.

Comment: Just a small correction. You divide by $10\sigma$ not just $\sigma$

Comment: @optimus257: indeed - I have made the correction